# Proof that the minimum area rectangle is collinear with an edge of the convex hull?

Tags: geometry, convex-hulls

If I have a finite set of points S, is there a way to prove that the minimum area rectangle containing all points in S will be collinear with one of the edges of the convex hull of S? As far as I can tell, this is assumed in every convex hull proof I can find, but I can't seem to find a proof of this assumption itself.

Comment: I think you have to stipulate that $S$ is finite. Otherwise its convex hull might not have any straight edges.

Comment: @TonyK good point. Making the edit to say that.